# How to avoid natural for node.js splitting words with special characters

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, nlp

I'm using [node natural](https://github.com/NaturalNode/natural) tokenizer feature, which splits a sentence into words. Usually it's supposed to work as

```
var natural = require('natural'),
tokenizer = new natural.WordTokenizer();
console.log(tokenizer.tokenize("your dog has't flees."));
// Returns [ 'your', 'dog', 'has', 'n't, 'flees' ]
```

It works fine, however, when used with German or French words, it splits up the words into two, such as

```
var natural = require('natural'),
tokenizer = new natural.WordTokenizer();
console.log(tokenizer.tokenize("fußball"));
// Returns ['fu', 'ball']
```

Which is not correct.

Anyone knows how to avoid that?

Or maybe you know a simplier way to split sentences into words in JavaScript / Node.js?

Thanks!

Comment: Remove the punctuation you don't want using a regex and then `sentence.split(' ');`?

Comment: But I'm talking about special accented characters, such as ß, ç etc. There are no problems with punctuation.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/Gk9jn/1/, `split` works fine, but you'll want to remove the full-stops and commas is all I'm saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = "your fußball, hasn't! flees.";

// Remove unwanted punctuation, in this case full-stops,
// commas, and exclamation marks.
data = data.replace(/[.,!]/g, '');

// split the words up
data.split(' '); // ["your", "fußball", "hasn't", "flees"]
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/Gk9jn/2/)

Answer (score 1):

The natural docs state

> [...] At the moment, most of the algorithms are English-specific

So, I wouldn't expect it to work out-of-the-box without some work on your part.

However, if all you want to do is split a string along whitespace boundaries, use something like this:

```
var s = "your dog hasn't flees.";
console.log(s.split(/\s+/)); // ["your", "dog", "hasn't", "flees."]
```